# Find superscript at beginning of line

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to use Word's find / replace to find superscripts that are at the beginning of lines? I've got complex units (e.g. cm s<sup>-1</sup>) in a long document and sometimes the <sup>-1</sup> is wrapped onto a new line - I'd like to find anywhere this happens.

I've tried using `^p` in the find box (along with setting the font to subscript), but this doesn't find these cases.

Comment: But I specifically only want to find them when they're at the beginning of a line...

Answer (score 1):

If you’re talking about line breaks that are created automatically by Word
as part of the text justification process (i.e., because the text reached the right margin),
then I doubt that this will be possible. 
But I suspect that this isn’t really your problem; I suspect that your problem is

> How do I get expressions containing minus signs, including superscripted ones, e.g.,
>
> > The quick brown fox jumps at 10 cm s<sup>-1</sup> over the lazy dog.
>
> not to break at the right margin, as if the minus sign were a hyphen:
>
> > blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  …  The quick brown fox jumps at 10 cm s<sup>-</sup>
> >     <sup>1</sup> over the lazy dog.
> >     ?

and, if that’s your problem,
then see [Preventing line breaks in superscript](https://superuser.com/q/508871/150988). 
Specifically, I recommend the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>**-**</kbd> answer. 
If you have a large document, you’ll probably want to do a “Find and Replace”,
replacing superscripted hyphens with non-breaking hyphens (using the `^~` code):
            [image: “Find and Replace” dialog box]

Comment: As you've probably already realised, that was also my question! The answers to that were good, but I need to find out where it's happening before I can fix them :) doing it manually (searching for **all** superscripts) in a 80,000 word document is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to help you find hyphens that should be minus signs. In the Find/Replace dialog box, open the More options and enable Use Wildcards. The pattern `-[ 0-9]` will find hyphens followed by a digit or space. The vast majority of those should be written with a minus sign (for negative numbers) or en-dash (for dates and numeric ranges). For more information on Word regular expressions, see the [Office.com help article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx).

It's a good idea to fix all hyphen errors and not just the ones that are currently wrapped incorrectly. Line breaks change often, and a hyphen that looks OK today might break tomorrow. Also, [proper minus signs and dashes look different from hyphens](http://www.punctuationmatters.com/the-difference-between-a-dash-and-a-minus-sign/), and sophisticated readers can tell the difference. A non-breaking hyphen will fix the line wrap, but it's still the wrong size and height for a minus sign. An en-dash will generally have the opposite problem: looks right, wraps wrong.